# Need to pass arguments to method decorator from inherited class

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance, pycharm, python-decorators

I am working in pycharm, and am trying to pass arguments to a pagination decorator which i used to decorate a method of a class.

I have created a class where to abstract the attributes of a given resource the API returns. I also have a dictionary `resource_vars` where I keep track of the different variables that particular resource has been given by the api developer (for example, the name I want to give to that resource, what is the pagination limit for that resource etc.).

```
class Resource:
    def __init__(self, resource, resource_vars):
        self.resource = resource
        self.resource_vars = resource_vars
        self.resource_name = resource_vars["name"]
        self.total_results = resource["total_results"] if "total_results" in resource else None
        self.max_items_allowed = resource_vars["items_per_page"] if "items_per_page" in resource_vars else None
```

I then have a second class, where I am trying to implement the factory design pattern, because every Resource returned has a certain set of conditionals and mutation that needs to happen before inserting the object in the database.

```
class ResourceDispatcher(Resource):  # My understanding is that i am inheriting the class Resource attributes here.

    def dispatch(self, resource, resource_name):
        dispatcher = get_dispatcher(resource_name)  # factory function defined outside the class. 
        return dispatcher(resource)

    # pycharm underlines total_results and max_items_allowed in red with 
    # warning "unresolved reference total_results"

    @paginate(pages=total_results, items_per_page=max_items_allowed)
    def dispatch_object_1(...) :
        ...
```

The warning pops up when I am trying to decorate the method `dispatch_object_1`.

I am wondering if it is at all possible to pass arguments to a decorator using attributes of an inherited class. If someone has any idea of how I could refactor to obtain this results I'd be happy to take them into account!